# How can I read output of an sql query into an ant property?

Tags: sql, ant

I would like to feed the result of a simple SQL query (something like: `select SP_NUMBER from SERVICE_PACK`) which I run inside my ant script (using the `sql` task) back into an ant property (e.g. `service.pack.number`).

The `sql` task can output to a file, but is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although I would have preferred not creating a file, I eventually went with the following solution:

The sql task is called as follows

```
<sql ... print="yes" output="temp.properties"
        expandProperties="true" showheaders="false" showtrailers="false" >
        <![CDATA[
        select 'current.sp.version=' || NAME from SERVICE_PACK;
        select 'current.major.version=' || NAME from VERSION;
        ]]>
</sql>
```

The generated properties file will contain:

```
current.sp.version=03

current.major.version=5
```

Then you just load the properties file and delete it:

```
<property file="temp.properties" />
<delete file="temp.properties" />

<echo message="Current service pack version: ${current.sp.version}" />
<echo message="Current major version: ${current.major.version}" />
```

This works, and everything is right there in the ant script (even if it's not the prettiest thing in the world!).

Comment: hi!
`select 'deployment_instruction=' deployment_instruction from Patch_spd where patch_name='${patch_name}'` i m running above query but in my properties file it's printing only pls help me out 
`deployment_instruction=` nothing else

Comment: Run your query directly against your database and check that it produces the correct result?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Ant [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task is more useful here ? You can execute a standalone and get the result in a property via `outputproperty`. You'll have to execute your SQL in some standalone fashion, unfortunately.

Alternatively is it worth looking at the code to the Ant Sql task and modify it to accept an `outputproperty` ? It sounds a bit of a pain, but I think it could well be a very simple modification if you can't find anything more direct.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Brian. I'm a bit weary of doing too much outside of my ant script, so I'm going with the approach described in my answer.

Comment: Thx for the feedback. Sounds like the most pragmatic solution for your requirements

Answer (score 0):

MySQL users- I had to modify the query like so:

```
SELECT CONCAT('mytable.id=', CAST(ID as CHAR)) from mytable
```

Without the CONCAT function, I just got back the text "1" (representing my id) in the properties file. Also, the CAST is needed in a MySQL system, otherwise the concatenated field is returned as a BLOB.